# Pass on variables to popup screen

Tags: php, javascript, popup

Well the title says it all,
I have a main screen where users see some data, and then they can click a button that opens a popup window using `window.open` .

But in the popup window I want to show some variables that are defined on the main screen along with some other variables that are calculated in the popup screen.

I tried using `$_SESSION`, but for some reason that doesn't work..
if anyone has idea on how to "pass" on the variables from the main screen to the popup screen/file using either JavaScript or PHP?

HTML :

```
<input type="button" value="Klik hier om uw terugverdientijd te berekenen" id="btnTerugverdientijd" onclick="basicPopup('/wp-content/themes/blackbird/phpwizard/HTML5Application/public_html/terugVerdientijd.php')" />
```

JavaScript :

```
function basicPopup(url) 
{
    popupWindow = window.open(url,'popUpWindow','height=500,width=500,left=1400,top=300,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');
}
```

Thanks for the time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with get method like

```
function basicPopup(url) 
{
    url = url + '?id=1221';
    popupWindow = window.open(url,'popUpWindow','height=500,width=500,left=1400,top=300,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');
}
```

and at your popup you try with

```
echo $_GET['id'];
```

thats it...

Comment: I already thought it would be easy haha, but thanks, I would have never came up with this!

Comment: I'll accept this one as the answer, still have to wait 7 mins though :P

Answer (score 0):

With javascript/jQuery you can append variables to your url then on server side you process them and display in the popup.

Answer (score 0):

I would pass the value via query string, e.g. terugVerdientijd.php?name1=value&name2=value2

This makes the coding a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Java Script 
        <script>
            function Popup(url) {
                var width = 700;
                var height = 500;
                var left = (screen.width - width) / 2;
                var top = (screen.height - height) / 2;
                var params = 'width=' + width + ', height=' + height;
                params += ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left;
                params += ', directories=no';
                params += ', location=no';
                params += ', menubar=no';
                params += ', resizable=yes';
                params += ', scrollbars=yes';
                params += ', status=no';
                params += ', toolbar=no';
                newwin = window.open(url, '_blank', params);
                //newwin = window.showModalDialog(url, 'popup', params);
                if (window.focus) { newwin.focus() }
                return false;
            }

        </script>
    //in any Button Event in your CS file Add



     protected void Raisepopup(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Chaubey = "123";
            string Rakesh = "../QueryString?Chaubey=" + Chaubey ;
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "temp", "<script type='text/javascript'>Popup('" + Rakesh + "');</script>", false);
        }


//Kindly reply if it resolves the Issue.
```